# python does not keep data when multiproccessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The script below does the following:

1) makes a data frame with 200 rows

2) sorts the df into a list of objects, multiprocessing so that each core does a quater of the df into their own list

3)sticks the lists together into a big list and prints

problem = the list is empty it's almost like the get_car_terms function wasn't called in each process with no error message

```
import random
import psutil
import pandas as pd
import multiprocessing as mp

class car_term(): #object to go into list 
    def __init__(self, capcode, miles,months , cmprice, fmprice ):
        self.capcode = capcode
        self.months = months
        self.miles = miles
        self.cmprice = cmprice
        self.fmprice = fmprice

df_final = pd.DataFrame({'capcode':[],'months':[],'mileage':[],'cm':[],'fm':[]})

for i in range (200): # making dataframe to get data from
    df_final.append(pd.DataFrame({'capcode':[i],'months':[random.randint(1, 12)],'mileage':[random.randint(0, 10000)],'cm':[random.randint(5, 700)],'fm':[random.randint(15, 710)]}))


all_deals=[] # this is the list i want to put my objects into
def get_car_terms(data,mdb1,all_deals1):
    all_deals1.append(car_term(mdb1['capcode'][data],mdb1['mileage'][data],mdb1['months'][data],mdb1['cm'][data],mdb1['fm'][data])) # i make the objects with the dataframe like this
all_deals1a=[]   # individual lists for each proccessor
all_deals2a=[]
all_deals3a=[]
all_deals4a=[]
print("yo1")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    n_cpus = psutil.cpu_count() # number of cpus
    print(n_cpus) # i have 4 cpus
    if df_final.shape[0]%n_cpus == 0:
        for i in range(int(df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)):

            ############# the problem is the get_car_terms function doesnt run below
            p1 = mp.Proccess(target = get_car_terms,args = (i+((df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)*1), df_final,all_deals1a)) # each cpu sorts a quater of the dataframe into my objects list
            p2 = mp.Proccess(target = get_car_terms,args = (i+((df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)*2), df_final,all_deals2a)) 
            p3 = mp.Proccess(target = get_car_terms,args = (i+((df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)*3), df_final,all_deals3a))
            p4 = mp.Proccess(target = get_car_terms,args = (i+((df_final.shape[0]/n_cpus)*4), df_final,all_deals4a))
            p1.start()
            p2.start()
            p3.start()
            p4.start()
            p1.end()
            p2.end()
            p3.end()
            p4.end()
    all_deals.append(all_deals1a)   # group lists together
    all_deals.append(all_deals2a)
    all_deals.append(all_deals3a)
    all_deals.append(all_deals4a)

print("we did it")
print(len(all_deals))  # this should have 200 of my objects in it... it doesnt
for i in all_deals:
    print(i.capcode)
```

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your code... First, mdb1 is not even defined.  I suspect df_final is mdb1.  Second, have you tried, without parallel processing, to see if get_car_terms works?

Comment: Why do you call `.end()` right after you call `.start()`? They need time to work.

Comment: 1) you were right about the mdb thing that was my bad, and 2, yes

Answer (score 0):

You called `.end()` right after `.start()`, so the multiprocessings did not get the time they need to work. I would recommend running `time.sleep(1)` between the starts and ends to give them the time they need.